# Backbone.js loads URL twice because of encoding mismatch

Tags: backbone.js

I'm still using Backbone.js and am having some problems with URL's loading twice (at least in Chrome) when there is JSON in the hash.

Say I want to navigate to this hash: `#{"name":"Viktor"}`. After encoding it with `encodeURIComponent('{"name":"Viktor"}')` it becomes `%7B%22name%22%3A%22Viktor%22%7D`.

If I then try to navigate to the hash like `this.navigate('%7B%22name%22%3A%22Viktor%22%7D')` Backbone decodes the hash to `#{"name":"Viktor"}` and saves it. Then a `hashchange` event is triggered which calls `Backbone.history.checkUrl()` which indirectly calls `Backbone.history.getHash()` and returns hash `#{%22name%22:%22Viktor%22}` from `window.location.href`, but this is only partly decoded, at least in Chrome.

This leads to the following check failing:

```
if (current === this.fragment) return false;
```

Because `#{"name":"Viktor"}` does not equal `#{%22name%22:%22Viktor%22}`. I think this is the gist of the problem. If I override `Backbone.history.getHash()` and replace `%22` with `"` my problem is solved, but I feel I should do something different?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue [is a bug](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/4085) fixed in Backbone 1.4, so I will suggest updating your Backbone version.

The only way I think it can be solved is patching Backbone as you done.

Comment: Why, thank you! I did a fair amount of googling, but never found that issue. I also did a compare of code between v1.3.last that we're on and v1.4, but did not spot anyhing.